# Blackscreen and freezing after installing Android-x86

Tags: android-x86

I installed Android-x86. After finishing installation and rebooting when I'm starting OS at first this screen appears

```
With A N D R O I D
```

and then an empty and black screen appears and nothing happens

I tried that on Virtualbox and PC

please help me

thanks